# R data.table complex filtering, grouping, assigning

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(structure(list(helpfulDescriptor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ugly_carpet","zestyTomato", "brexit-Vote"), class = "factor"), eventDate = structure(c(15162,15162, 15249, 15249, 15249, 15249, 15250, 15250, 15250, 15250,16868, 16883, 16883, 16883, 16883, 16883, 15414, 15414, 15414,15418, 15418, 16588, 16591, 16591, 15372, 15601, 15601, 16230,16423, 16577, 16577, 16827), class = "Date"), indicator = c(0L,0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("helpfulDescriptor","eventDate", "indicator"), class = c("data.table",     "data.frame")))

dt

    helpfulDescriptor  eventDate indicator
 1:       ugly_carpet 2011-07-07         0
 2:       ugly_carpet 2011-07-07         0
 3:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-02         0
 4:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-02         0
 5:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-02         0
 6:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-02         0
 7:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-03         0
 8:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-03         0
 9:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-03         0
10:       ugly_carpet 2011-10-03         0
11:       ugly_carpet 2016-03-08         0
12:       ugly_carpet 2016-03-23         0
13:       ugly_carpet 2016-03-23         0
14:       ugly_carpet 2016-03-23         0
15:       ugly_carpet 2016-03-23         0
16:       ugly_carpet 2016-03-23         0
17:       zestyTomato 2012-03-15         0
18:       zestyTomato 2012-03-15         0
19:       zestyTomato 2012-03-15         0
20:       zestyTomato 2012-03-19         0
21:       zestyTomato 2012-03-19         0
22:       zestyTomato 2015-06-02         0
23:       zestyTomato 2015-06-05         0
24:       zestyTomato 2015-06-05         0
25:       brexit-Vote 2012-02-02         0
26:       brexit-Vote 2012-09-18         0
27:       brexit-Vote 2012-09-18         0
28:       brexit-Vote 2014-06-09         0
29:       brexit-Vote 2014-12-19         0
30:       brexit-Vote 2015-05-22         0
31:       brexit-Vote 2015-05-22         0
32:       brexit-Vote 2016-01-27         0
```

I am struggling using data.table to identify all rows sharing the same, most recent, (max) date grouped by the helpfulDescriptor.

```
dt[eventDate == max(eventDate), indicator := 1L, by = c('helpfulDescriptor')]
```

This only sets indicator to 1 for the max date of the entire data.table, not grouping...

My other attempts utilizing tail, setkey(), .SD, ect... failed.

A correct solution would set indicator to 1 for the last (in this arranged list) most recent (dates) 5 rows of ugly_carpet, the 2 2015-06-05 zestyTomato, and the 1 final, or most recent brexitvotes.

Thank you.

Comment: `dt[dt[, .I[eventDate == max(eventDate)], by = helpfulDescriptor]$V1, indicator := 1]`

Comment: `dt[dt[, max(eventDate), by=helpfulDescriptor], on=c("helpfulDescriptor",eventDate = "V1"), indicator := 1]` is another option.

Comment: @Frank I think you need to modify this slightly: `on=c(helpfulDescriptor="helpfulDescriptor",  eventDate="V1")`.

Comment: Thanks @lmo . I'm on 1.9.7, where the syntax has changed, so I didn't realize.